# Disable dragging for a card based on certain criteria

Tags: rally

I'm working on a custom board to add some functionality I need for my teams. I am looking for the best (or any) way to prevent a card from being (and appearing) draggable based on certain critera - for example, when Ready == false, or the current user is not the owner, etc. I've extended CardBoard, Column and Card for good measure, so I have quite a lot of freedom, but I just can't seem to figure out where I need to plug in. I could post some code but nothing I've tried so far has worked, so I'm not sure how much merit there would be to that. If anyone has done anything similar, some hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter Popov

Answer (score 1):

Since you've extended [Rally.ui.cardboard.Column](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.Column), you may wish to check out the [dropControllerConfig](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.Column-cfg-dropControllerConfig). This allows you to specify a [Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.ColumnDropController](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.ColumnDropController). The drop controller allows you to provide methods such as [canDragDropCard](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.ColumnDropController-method-canDragDropCard). Here you can code some logic specifying when this function returns true, according to the conditions you prefer to allow a Card to be draggable.

Note that Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.ColumnDropController is marked as Private, and may not be guaranteed to exist forever. Perhaps one of Rally's developers can comment on whether or not it's a good idea to rely on this plugin in your code.

Comment: Thanks Mark. We took a quick and dirty approach before you responded. What we did was extend Column and override addDragDropHandle():

    addDragDropHandle: function(card) {
        card[card.canDragDropCard() ? 'addCls' : 'removeCls'](cardDraggableCls);
    }

card.canDragDropCard() is a public method that returns true based on whatever business logic we want implemented.

This works, but we don't like it very much so we'll refactor in the way you describe. I'm a bit confused why a private class has public methods, so I'll make the bold assumption that it's supposed to be extendable.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, the quick-and-dirty approach we implemented is to extend Column and override this method:

    addDragDropHandle: function(card) {
        card[card.canDragDropCard() ? 'addCls' : 'removeCls']('drag-handle');
    }